# Newline inside variable in div

Tags: babeljs, jsx

Is it possible to use a variable in `<div>` with newline inside?

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {

    const texts = {
        subHeaderText: 'first line \n second line'
    };

    return <div>{texts.subHeaderText}</div>;
  }
}
```

I wish to result

```
first line 
second line
```

What is the simplest way?

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/263117/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use p (paragraph) tags.
check out this site:
https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/newline-in-react-string-solved/68484/7

Answer (score 0):

```
div{
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

Add this to the css file of your html. This will automatically create line breaks whenever `/n` or `<br>` are encountered. This is the simplest way.

As a recommendation, since it looks like a hardcode you might as well use two separate `<p>` or `<div>` for both like so:

```
<div>
    <p>
         first line
    </p>
    <p>
         second line
    </p>
</div>
```

It's just much more elegant that way unless you really want to display line breaks from input. Given that you may also approach it in a js way like so:

```
texts.subHeaderText.split('\n').map((item, i) => {
    return <p key={i}>{item}</p>;
});
```